# Linked Table Manager: Need MS Access VBA code to change the file location of MS Excel file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a 2013 MS Access database with multiple users in different locations. I have several excel files as Linked Tables. The Excel files are located on a share drive so all users can access the information. The problem we are experiencing is the share drive is slow so it takes long periods for our reports to load.

I would like VBA code, when the user opens the database, the share drive Excel files are automatically downloaded to the their local profile desktop. Each user profile of course is different so the Linked Table has to know to change the person profile name: "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username")& "\Desktop\Reports". The Link Table Manager will not allow Environ("Username") so it will have to done likely in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Code for changing link path to an Excel sheet. This requires a link with worksheet to have already been established and link object exists in db.

```
Sub ChangeExcelLink()
Dim Tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim Db As DAO.Database
Set Db = CurrentDb
Set Tdf = Db.TableDefs("link table name")
Tdf.Connect = "Excel 12.0;DATABASE=C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & _
     "\Desktop\Reports\filename.xlsx;HDR=NO"
Tdf.RefreshLink
Set Tdf = Nothing
Set Db = Nothing
End Sub
```

If worksheet has column headers you want to retain, change `HDR=No` to `HDR=Yes` or remove that argument because Yes is default. If database requires password, use `;PWD=yourpassword`.

Comment: Thank you for sending the code, but it seems to only exports the respective table to the identified location as an Excel spreadsheet. However, I would like to change the Linked Table Manager's file location using VBA.

Comment: Don't understand comment. Code sets link to spreadsheet. Isn't that what you asked for? Now add your code that first copies the file.

Comment: Than you! I tried the code again and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: One additional question. The spreadsheets that are linked already have column header titles, but I noticed when the Linked tables are re-linked in the database the headers are now numbers. How do I select the existing headers?

Comment: Sorry, I did not actually open the table link to see that, just saw that link path was changed. Change `HDR=NO` to `HDR=Yes` or remove that argument because Yes is default.